# Translate theme specific transactional emails in Magento 1.7

Tags: magento, email, configuration, localization

Is it possible to have your transactional emails (app/locale/en_US/template/email/*.csv) be dependent on the current active theme? There's a setting in System > Design > Themes > Translations, but I can't understand what the effect of this setting is.

Answer (score 0):

you can select as per this document to define transaction email as per store view if you are in franc store you can pick from left bar first and then go to this step to create your language specific.

just go to [this link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/customizing-transactional-emails)